# Script to autoclick an application popup

Tags: windows

Sorry if this is the wrong place to ask but wasn't sure where to go.  I have a very annoying application that I have to have running, and every 5 minutes it pops up a box saying 'you will be disconnected due to inactivity, click 'continue' to halt the disconnection'.  Can anyone suggest a program or scripting tool I could use to auto-click this annoying pop-up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to make is something that's usually called macro or script.

If you're unfamiliar with programming languages I would suggest using something like [JitBit Macro Recorder](https://www.jitbit.com/macro-recorder/).

You'll be able to simply record the color of the checkbox and check for that color at that exact spot every second (or whatever you prefer). It's easy to use but the downside of this tool is that you'll only be able to use it for 30 days before you'll have to pay for it.

In case you've got at least a tiny bit programming experience I'd recommend using @remco1250's solution instead, as it has more options and is actually free (as in beer).

Comment: Sounds like a great solution for me, and I don't mind paying to get this thing done.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/). It requires some programming knowledge, but it does exactly what you want.